# How to write (or overwrite) to file with URI provided by the OpenDocumentTree picker directory picker?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My app creates a text document which I would like to write to public shared storage ("Documents/myApp/Reports") with the intention that it remains accessible and write-able even if the user uninstalls/reinstalls the app. At runtime the user sees an OpenDocumentTree picker and chooses the folder. However, I find that after uninstall/reinstall of the app, even after showing the picker again, the file is not accessible and throws an "Access denied..." error.

Min API = 6 and target API = 11.

I have not been able to figure out what I am doing incorrectly. Any help would be SO appreciated!

This is the ActivityOnResult() code (following StartActivityForResult(myIntent, requestReportAccess)):

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == requestReportAccess)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    // I can get flags here
                    var takeFlags = data.Flags & ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission;

                    // I can get the uri here
                    Android.Net.Uri myUri = data.Data;

                    // This works until user uninstalls/reinstalls app
                    try 
                    {
                        var externalCopyOfReport = System.IO.Path.Combine(externalReportFolder, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.MileageReportFile));

                        //Write the text to a file. Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.
                        File.WriteAllText(externalCopyOfReport, mileageReportAsString.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Do something here
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `myUri = data.Data;` You are not using myUri.

Comment: It is unclear wich folder is choosen by the user and who created those subfolders.

Comment: `How to write (or overwrite) to file with URI provided by the OpenDocumentTree picker directory picker?` Wrong question as OpenDocumentTree will give you an uri for a folder. Not for a file.

Comment: You can just write your file to that directory without using OpenDocumentTree(). And indeed after reinstall your app will not 'see' it anymore. But you can let the user choose the file with OpenDocument().

Comment: @blackapps I create the directory structure on first run of the app. It is my understanding that in the selected directory (I direct them to the needed directory with a short dialog) all the files and folders in that directory (or below) have RW permissions after user selection. I realize I need to use the URI somehow but I do not understand how. Hoping you can help!

Comment: You do not need that uri. I said that before. And.. you have seen you dont need that uri as you didnot use it.

Comment: @blackapps, so using the uri does not somehow allow access to the file after a reinstall of the app by the user? Isn't that the point of the picker - to allow the user to grant access to the file by my app?

Comment: You are not using that uri. Third time i tell you.

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to help me. I do appreciate it!